# How to convert a value from a text input into an array for Google Visualization API using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I want to convert a text input value in CSV format into an array that suits Google Visualization API using PHP.

While the CSV has this format:

```
                        Aguascalientes,204
                        Baja California,996
                        Baja California Sur,173
```

I need to **echo** something like this:

```
                        ['Aguascalientes',204],
                        ['Baja California',996],
                        ['Baja California Sur',173],
```

Using javascript isn't an option and by the time I'm running out of ideas.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_getcsv` for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

```
$data = str_getcsv($string, "\n");
foreach($data as &$row) $row = str_getcsv($row, ",");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the data. Anyway, I had to solve the issue in another way. Here is the full code:

`<?php $row = 1; if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) { while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { $num = count($data); $row++; for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { if($c&1) { echo $data[$c] . "],['"; } else { echo $data[$c] . "',"; } } } fclose($handle); } ?>`